# Designing efficient social media database in Parse?

Tags: ios, mongodb, performance, parse-platform, database

### Preface

In a social media application, user activities (liking a post, commenting, and following a user) must be stored in a database/class. In Parse's [Anypic tutorial, they implement this storage by combining all of these activities into one table/class called "`Activity`"](https://parse.com/tutorials/anypic#model).

### TL;DR

If you don't want to look at the link above, this model essentially consists of an "Activity" object having a `type` string (ex. "follow", "comment", "like"), a `fromUser` and `toUser` property that are pointers to `User` objects, and a `Post` property that is a pointer to the relevant `Post` object. Information such as users a user is following is obtained by searching all of the `Type` and `fromUser` properties of objects and matching them to a given type and user.

### Problem

As I am about to implement similar behavior into my app, Anypic's model struck me as particularly inefficient and unscalable. If an app were to grow to a user base in the thousands and beyond - with all of their likes, comments, and follows thrown into one table - it seems to me that essential tasks (such as finding the Users a person follows) would become exceedingly sluggish, as it would require sifting through huge quantities of objects.

### Potential Solutions

I have thought of two seemingly more efficient alternatives:

1. Separating Activities into respective tables/classes: i.e. having a "Follow", "Like", and "Comment" table/class that are populated by their respective activity
2. Adding properties (columns in Parse) to a `User` object that contain arrays of their activities; i.e. a "Following" column, "Liked" column, and "Comments" column

Could someone more familiar with databases and working with this type of data than I provide their insight? Am I mistaken in my assumptions about Parse's data model? What would be the optimal approach to this problem? I believe Parse uses MongoDB (noSQL). 
Thank you to all!

### ***UPDATE / EDIT : DEC-3-2014***

After a few months of development my question still stand - however I have made some progress. Currently I have the classes separated and they are working well - with about 3 users (and the app isn't even live yet). I have reached a point where an answer to this question is crucial - how do I handle very frequent activities such as likes? I would imagine having one class for likes would become overwhelming in size since it is such a common activity. My proposed methods above essentially still stand: either having a "`Like`" class, or attaching a "`Liked`" property to either the `User` or `Post` objects. If anyone has experience with this sort of problem and could contribute their two cents I would be more than grateful!

Comment: I have just quickly read through your question, but sounds to make sense to me. Either having each Class, as you mention, with relevant pointers. Or, keeping Relations which keep pointers to "Follow", "Like" and "Comment". Relations can in some cases be easier to manage, but they can introduce circular dependencies if you also store pointers to parents (maybe just me, but I created some problems for myself in that regard).

Comment: @cYrixmorten Good info! For the time being, I'm going to implement the separate classes - but the answer box is still open! :)

Comment: No problem - do not think it counts as an answer :) by the way (have not look into Anypic) I came to think that maybe they are using a single class to minimize the amount of queries. Just realized that it will take 3 queries when split into classes. If you simply want to show the amount of "Likes" and "Comments" on a Post until the user opens to get more details, then I find it best to store counters on the Post, then update the counter in Cloud Code using 'afterSave' on each class (assuming they have a pointer to the parent Post to fetch and update it).

Answer (score 0):

You can have something like this:

1. Seperate Classes for Posts, Comments and Likes
2. For Comments & Likes, have reference to "Posts", "fromUser", "postOwnerUser"
3. For "Posts" Class, have a relation column which contains all the likes & comments. (Redundancy is not that serious problem in this case if you properly manage).
4. Have LikesCounter and CommentsCounter fields on every Posts object. Update it on every like/dislike or comment add/delete.
5. Have an Activity class and store every post,like, comment metadata in this.
6. Save your followers in a relation and do query all the activities which are having fromUser in this relation to form the newsfeed.